# How to return all records and whether a related record exists?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Using Entity Framework 4 CTP5 I have a basic model and a basic DbContext that works

```
public class Customer {
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
  public int Name { get; set; }
  //...
  public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
  public bool HasAddress {
    get {
      return Addresses.Count > 0;
    }
  }
}

public class Address {
  public int AddressId { get; set; }
  public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }
  //....
  public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

How can I query my DbContext to return all customers and whether they have an address?

A customer can have multiple addresses and I don't want to return all the addresses for each customer when I am only interested in whether they have an address or not.  I use 
`context.Customers.Include(c => c.Addresses)` but that returns all addresses for each customer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind, in order to *determine* if a Customer has addresses, an aggregate operation (COUNT) must be done on the server. I don't think you can use that `HasAddress` property directly in the LINQ predicate, as AFAIK aggregate operations cannot be used in LINQ-Entities predicates.

So you might have to do something like this:

```
var result = ctx.Customers.Select(x => new
                                  {
                                     Customer = x,
                                     HasAddress = x.Addresses.Count() > 0
                                  }).ToList();
```

That will return a collection of *anonymous types*, including *all* Customers, and whether they have at least one address.

Note the `()` on the Count - this performs an actual aggregate operation - whilst `.Count` is a client-side LINQ operation.

### Edit

If you want to put that anonymous type back into a Customer object, you can do this *after* the query has materialized (e.g ensuring the `.Count()` has been done on the database):

```
var result = ctx.Customers.Select(x => new
                                      {
                                         Customer = x,
                                         HasAddress = x.Addresses.Count() > 0
                                      }).ToList()
                                      .Select(x => new Customer
                                      {
                                         // left to right copy....
                                         HasAddress = true
                                      }).ToList();
```

Which is pretty dirty IMO, but it'll work.

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to project the x.Addresses.Count() > 0 into a HasAddress property of the Customer object? I would like to keep my model clean and the additional anonymous type is kind of like a view model

Comment: You can keep your property as it is - using `.Count` (no `()`), but it will be a client-side operation on the sequence (e.g after the query has been executed). You just won't be able to use it in the predicate as i mentioned. And yes - project into another class/type by all means if that suits.

Comment: i added an edit to show how you can put it back into Customer object. But it's fairly dirty. I don't know of a better way.

Comment: The problem is your in the difficult scenario of wanting to see if a customer has an address, but not actually retrieving it. Maybe you should `.Take(1)` address, which is not costly and much cleaner than the above and saves you left-to-right copying the properties from the anon type to the Customer object.